# envio de imagem ou video via webservice

Tags: php, ios, swift

Tenho em minha aplicação um atributo UIIMAGE ( para imagem) e um NSURL para o video, preciso passar uma dessas informações via webService... 
Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Não sei se é uma boa idéia, mas o pessoal da faculdade com quem temos webservice usa o base64. Deve ficar gigantesco, mas funciona

Comment: Pera aí, você precisa enviar o arquivo físicamente, ou apenas a informação do mesmo? Se for apenas a segunda opção, esqueça o que falei anteriormente

Comment: Preciso do arquivo próprio  , pensei em uso do ftp... Usar a base vai ficar difícil consulta

Comment: Existe algum problema em fazer o upload e salvar a url do arquivo no banco, e oferecer esse link via webservice, para acesso do mesmo?

Comment: Na realidade ao subir a foto irei registrar no banco um id e irei renomear o arquivo com esse id , e n acessarei a foto pelo app apenas por uma aplicacao web ...

Comment: Olá Augusto, aqui na empresa utilizamos a conversão da imagem para base64, e aí enviamos a string resultante para o servidor... lá ele se vira transformando em imagem novamente. Acredito que essa seja uma das melhores opções...

Comment: Acho que esse framework, pode lhe ajudar. https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage